# How to convert a date to UTC

Tags: java, date

I need to change de format of a date to UTC format.

> File file = new File();

...

> file.lastModified();

I need to convert the lastModified date of a file in UTC format.

Comment: Could you explain why you need this. Usually timezone formatting is just, well, a formatting issue, e.g. when you display things to the user. But then you either want to use the current system locale or a locale the user has specified, but rarely a fixed timezone such as UTC. Note that timestamps are independent of timezones. It's just the number of miliseconds since the Epoch.

Comment: As Erik said, the date is already in UTC. All you need to do is to format it using a desired `TimeZone`. Hint: `DateFormat` and `SimpleDateFormat`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
String lv_dateFormateInUTC=""; //Will hold the final converted date      
SimpleDateFormat lv_formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(); 
lv_formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));  
lv_dateFormateInUTC = lv_formatter.format(lv_localDate);
```

Something like that...!!

Answer (score 7):

Quite simply:

```
Date date = new Date(file.lastModified())
```

This works because the `long` value returned by `File.lastModified()` represents the number of milliseconds since the epoch (00:00:00 GMT, January 1, 1970) as stated in the [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#lastModified%28%29). And the same is true of `java.util.Date`. So they are both in UTC/GMT already. When a date is converted to a string such as via `Date.toString()` or a [DateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) object, it's typically expressed in the local timezone, but the `long` value it stores is timezone-agnostic.