# Hibernate date issue on servers in different timezones

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, date, datetime

I have a date stored in a database as a UTC date ('2015-04-24 00:00:00').  When I get this date (using Hibernate) on a server running in the Eastern US Timezone, is shown as the correct date, '2015-04-24 00:00:00'.  However, when I get this data on a server running on AWS in the us-west-1 region, which I assume is Pacific Time, the date shows as '2015-04-23 20:00:00'.  Does anyone know why this would happen? I assume it has something to do with the date converting to local time, rather than UTC, but how can I prevent this from happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Just convert your [Date to utc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5264442/66686)

Somewhat longer answer: As long as we don't consider relativistic effects a date (or more appropriately named a point in time) doesn't have a time zone. But if you display it as a String there are many variants of displaying it. One kind of variation is the choice of a timezone.

If you don't take special care to use a specific time zone, many programs will choose the timezone that the machine is 'living' in, which is configured on the os level and set to the time zone that is apropriate for the location the computer is most of the time.