# Unable to import LastModifiedFileComparator in Android

Tags: android, gradle-dependencies

I'm trying to use LastModifiedFileComparator referring http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-sort-an-array-of-files-according-to-their-last-modified-dates.html in Android.LastModifiedFileComparator isnt being resolved by using the import statement -

```
import org.apache.commons.io.comparator.LastModifiedFileComparator;
```

I've added the following statement in the dependencies, but it's still not working. Please help.

```
 compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
```

Answer (score 1):

guys If you are not able to resolve this `LastModifiedFileComparator` problem, Here is the solution I have found.

Step 1
Open app level `build.gradle`
and add dependency as below. To get updated version click [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io)

```
implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.0.1'
```

Step 2
If it did't work than Add `mavenCentral()`  creating new `repositories` in your app level `build.gradle`

```
repositories{
   mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
//all implementation
```

That all It should work like charm, If not please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26582070/sorting-files-based-on-its-creation-date-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `mavenCentral()` in repositories in Project level Gradle File.