# How can i get the time of creation of a file and put it in an array?

Tags: java, android

How can i get the time of creation of the files that are in a folder and then put in them in a string array?

This is the code use for read the files of the folder and then put them in a string array:final

```
File carpeta = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/cc.openframeworks.androidMultiOFActivitiesExample/files/xml");

listarFicherosPorCarpeta(carpeta);

  List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void listarFicherosPorCarpeta(final File carpeta) {
        for (final File ficheroEntrada: carpeta.listFiles()) {

            if (ficheroEntrada.isDirectory()) {
                listarFicherosPorCarpeta(ficheroEntrada);
            } else {
                System.out.println(ficheroEntrada.getName());
                    list.add(ficheroEntrada.getName());

            }
        }
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: I need to display the timestamp of creation in a listview row above the name of file creation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: How to get a file's creation date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389225/android-how-to-get-a-files-creation-date)

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File(filePath);
Date lastModDate = new Date(file.lastModified());
Log.i("File last modified @ : "+ lastModDate.toString());
```

Credit to [Android: How to get a file's creation date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389225/android-how-to-get-a-files-creation-date?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: I have an error : unhandeled exeption java.io.IOException

Answer (score 0):

If you are on API 26 or above, use [BasicFileAttributes](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes).

```
BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(filePath, BasicFileAttributes.class);
long creationTime = attr.creationTime().toMillis();
```

Comment: This one throws me : Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 1969