# How can I use android.hardware.usb with c# using jni to read the usb storage in Unity 2018 android app?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, java-native-interface, usb

I am struggling to understand JNI for my code. I am trying to retrieve connected usb storage device path using c# in my VS 2017 app with unity 2018 for android. I am not sure I understand Java properly.

Can someone help me with getting connected USB storage in my android app using JNI and c#?

Comment: First get the c# code to read and/or write to the storage device before attempting the JAVA code.  The storage device could require a certificate to access if it is a smart drive.  You may also need to search the PC for the USB device because the com number can change.

Comment: I did, I tried.. I am using driveinfo.get drives in pc and t works. I need to get the usb storage path in android. DriveInfo doesn't work on android.

Comment: See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389225/android-how-to-get-a-files-creation-date

Comment: Can I use xamarin with unity + vs2017?

Comment: Second link was irrelevant. I never mentioned I need to check file creation date

Comment: I cross checked earlier. I can't use xamarin with unity.